# Wrapper is not defined in Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test one of my React components but receive the following error:

```
ReferenceError: wrapper is not defined
```

```js
describe('TodaysHabits', () => {
  let component;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow( < TodayHabits / > );
  });
  test('it exists', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toExist;
  });
  test('it contains an p tag', () => {
    const p = wrapper.find('p');
    expect(p.text()).toBe('this is display habits');
  });
});
```

index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import './todayhabits.css';

class TodayHabits extends React.Component {
  // This component will show the habits that the user has to complete this specific day
  // To do this we need to make a api call to get all habits where they have the respective day as true in the sql
  state = {
    dailyHabits: [],
  }

  //for each habit, it will display a new habit component
  //we need to pass a prop to each habit component containing that habit's id and title

  displayHabits () {
    return <p>this is display habits</p>
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id='dailyHabits'>
        { moment().format('dddd') }, <br/>
        { moment().format("Do MMMM YYYY") } <br/>
        {this.displayHabits()}
        <button onClick={() => { history.push(`/newHabit`) }}>Add a habit!</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default TodayHabits;
```

I tried doing more research on fixing this error but it wasn't successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try declaring `wrapper` as a variable?

You're not declaring the variable and directly assigning a value to it.

```js
describe('TodaysHabits', () => {
  let component;
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow( < TodayHabits / > );
  });
  test('it exists', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toExist;
  });
  test('it contains an p tag', () => {
    const p = wrapper.find('p');
    expect(p.text()).toBe('this is display habits');
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you share the whole test file ?

Comment: the code in the question is the whole test file.

Comment: i have updated again, can you try again? i have defined wrapper on a scope above

Comment: have you imported shallow from enzyme ? 

like this

`import { shallow } from 'enzyme';`

Comment: hi, thanks that got rid of the error, but now im getting a different error that ".find" is undefined of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined" for this line of code " test('it contains an p tag', () => {
    > 13 |       const p = wrapper.find('p');"

Comment: you should create a codesandbox with your code to debug.